# How to add event for image

Tags: java, awt

I want to add and event on image. That is, when I click on the image, it should be replaced with another image.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class RadioButtonLoader extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    BufferedImage image = null;
    public RadioButtonLoader(){
        try {
            this.image = ImageIO.read(new File("res/rb1.gif"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public RadioButtonLoader(String checked){
        try {
            this.image = ImageIO.read(new File("res/rb2.gif"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setSize(Dimension d) {
        super.setSize(new Dimension(15,22));
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        setSize(new Dimension(15,22));
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);


    }   

}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You are back to setting the size in `paint()`?!?  Still using `null` for the `ImageObserver`?  Just how many times do you need to be told?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you add mouselistner in your image in mouselister onclick method add your code...............

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_full_screen_image_viewer.xml

Comment: [`java.awt.MouseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) (as opposed to `mouselistner` **or** `mouselister`) does not have an `onclick` method, though it does have a [MouseListener.mouseClicked(MouseEvent)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseClicked%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) method.  BTW - the linked source mixes Swing & AWT, but fails to then use `JFrame.setDefaultOperationOnClose(int)`, further it does custom painting using `paint(Graphics)` in a Swing top level container (ick).